# Need to write c# method taking a generic class I create as an argument and parsing out th values of the Properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have a number of classes in a project I am working on to simplify working with data that needs to be read in and out of text files, and assigned to data objects in my program. I need to write a method to take any one of these classes and return a csv string of the values. Similarly, I would like to be able to return a csv string of the property names. I could write specific methods for each class, but am trying to do this generically in a way that only have one method to do this.

Example class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentID;
    public string Form;
    public string ScaleForm;
    public double Totalscore;
    public double MatrixRawScore;
    public double ScaleScore;
    public double Theta;
    public int PerformanceLevel;
    public double LowScaleScore;
    public double HighScalescore;
    public string AdminID;
    public string Group;
    public int GroupIndex;
    public string ResponseVector;
}
```

Here is my effort to achieve my goal, but this clearly doesn't work:

```
    public static string ObjectToCsv<T>(T myObject)
    {
        var fields = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var objectString = "";

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in fields)
        {
            objectString = prop.GetValue(myObject, null).ToString() + ',';
        }
        objectString.TrimEnd(',');
        return objectString;
    }
```

When my code runs this method, PropertyInfo[] is length 0, there are no PropertyInfos, and so the method returns a blank string. Any thoughts about what I might need to do to make this work?

Code block edited to reflect suggestion below.

Comment: Where is `fields` getting set? And you may want to look at [string.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) that doesn't modify the current string it returns the modified string

Comment: That line got dropped accidentally, code edited to reflect missing line.

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem, you should click the checkmark to the upper-left of the answer. This will give you points and a shiny new badge!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the line of code that get the properties(and initialize your fields variable)

```
typeof(T).GetProperties();
```

in your case you need to add the below:

```
var fields = myObject.GetType().GetProperties();
```

I would make the field in your class autoproperty as showed below:

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentID { get; set;}
    public string Form { get ; set;}
    ...
}
```

bear in mind that `GetProperties()` method has an overload that gets a `BindingFlags` to add constrains on the returned properties.

- You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static in order to get a return.
- Specify BindingFlags.Public to include public properties in the search.
- Specify BindingFlags.NonPublic to include non-public properties (that is, private, internal, and  protected properties) in the search. Only protected and internal properties on base classes are returned; private properties on base classes are not returned.
- Specify BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy to include public and protected static members up the hierarchy; private static members in inherited classes are not included.
- BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly to search only the properties declared on the Type, not properties that were simply inherited

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx

Comment: Using this line: var fields = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public); returns no PropertyInfos in my code above either.

Comment: var fields = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance); also returns no results.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something a little more like this:

```
   public static string ObjectToCsv<T>(T myObject)
{
    var objectString = "";

    foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(T).GetFields())
    {
        objectString += field.GetValue(myObject).ToString() + ',';
    }
    return objectString.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

From what you've posted, it looks like you're dealing with fields, not properties. Also, you'll want to += your string instead of setting its' value, otherwise you'll just override it every time you feed it a new field. For some reason TrimEnd() didn't work for me, but I'll leave that out there. Good luck!

Edit: TrimEnd() fixed.

Comment: This was my answer! Thanks! Also, trim end not working for me either, but that I can fix.

Comment: a +1 would be appreciated if this was helpful. The way I handled the TrimEnd() in my recent CSV converter was to check for fields.Length()-1 and only add the comma when this was false, but that would require changing your foreach() to a for. Something to think about. TrimEnd is a much more elegant solution, I'm not sure why it's failing.

Comment: I just used Trim instead of TrimEnd and it worked fine. I tried to +1, but it would not let me because I have <15 Reputation.